# PowerShell 400 Bad Request Response Body

Tags: powershell

I'm trying print response body after getting status 400.

```bsh
try {
    if ($Responses = (Invoke-WebRequest @Param -ErrorAction Stop)) {
        $StatusCodes = $([int]$Responses.BaseResponse.StatusCode)
    }
    Write-Host ("State code : " + $StatusCodes)
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    $StatusCodes = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__;
    $Messages = (($_.ErrorDetails.Message) | ConvertFrom-Json).Message;
    Write-Host ("State code : " + $StatusCodes);
    Write-Host ("Message: " + $Messages)
}
```

My code is working for only status code. I want print error response body

```json
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "warnings": {
        "errorCode": ",
        "errorDesc": " "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error response doesn't have the kind of body you seem to expect. If you want something like that you need to build it yourself.

```
try {
    ...
} catch [Net.WebException] {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
       'status'   = 'Failed'
       'warnings' = @{
           'errorCode' = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
           'errorDesc' = $_.Exception.Message
       }
    } | ConvertTo-Json
}
```